# CICS Explorer bundle could not be resolved

Tags: bundle, osgi-bundle, cics

I am working on a simple Java-DB2 insert program connected to cics region via CICS explorer. I created a plugin for an external jar(com.ibm.db2.jcc), exported the plugin as a deployable plugin and added this in the build path of the program. The package has also been added in the dependencies (import-package) of the program. But installing the bundle in the cics region, I am getting an exception.

```
The bundle ABC could not be resolved. Reason:Missing constraint:Import-package:com.ibm.db2.jcc;version="0.0.0".
```

Can someone help me trace the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the program you're writing is in an OSGi bundle that's being deployed into a CICS JVM Server as your OSGi environment, using CICS's OSGi CICS bundle parts.  It sounds like you're taking an existing binary dependency and rebundling it as an OSGi bundle, and want to have your program resolve it using OSGi.

Based on these assumptions, it sounds like you're having to add the bundle to your build path automatically, which I don't think you should have to do.  Once you've set up your target platform (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.ts.java.doc%2Ftopics%2Fdeveloping_sdk.html) any dependencies should then be resolved either from OSGi bundles in your workspace, or your target platform.  It should then just be a case of adding an OSGi bundle part for each of your bundles, and exporting your CICS bundle to your region.  Explorer should take care of exporting all of your relevant dependencies to CICS.

If you wanted, it should be possible to add the DB2 jar file as a lib without rebundling as an OSGi bundle, by adding the library to your Bundle-Classpath manifest declaration, but you might already have considered this!